# LiveReload for Sublime Text 3 - Not working

Tags: sublimetext3, livereload

I have setup LiveReload for Sublime Text 3 by following this guide [image: here].

I have installed the LiveReload Plugin for FireFox (it's enabled).

I have tested it with this simple HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some **weird** reason it doesn't work. What might cause this issue?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/Yuriy-Svetlov/live-reload-bp/tree/main/documentation/examples/nodejs/3

Answer (score 10):

**Solution:**

- Open the command palette with
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Type LiveReload
- When 'Enable/disable plugins' is highlighted, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Or

- Go to Preferences > Package Settings > LiveReload > Plugins > Enable/disable plugins and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I have to enable each time I reboot sublime text, how auto enable plugin?

Answer (score 0):

In case of chrome, click on the three dots at the top-right corner of the browser. Go to more tools>extensions>find the live reload extension.Click on the details and then allow access to the file URL [as shown in the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGsh5.png)
After having done that, go to the sublime text. Go to preferences>Package Settings>LiveReload>plugin and click on Enable/Disable plugins.
(If the plugin was disabled, it would get enabled and vice versa)
Then, do not forget to close both the browser and sublime text and reopen both.
This should do the trick.